# Determine if CurrentCulture's AbbreviatedMonthNames are just numbers or not

Tags: c#, .net, localization, globalization

for example

`var culc = new CultureInfo("ja");`

`culc.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames`

Will return `string[13] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "" }`

Is there a more elegant way of determining if currentculture has proper abberviated names or they just contain numbers, without having to just check the first element to determine if its a number or not

Answer (score 0):

Numbers *are* proper abbreviated month names for Japanese culture.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_calendar#Months):

> The modern Japanese names for the months literally translate to
>   "first month", "second month", and so on. The corresponding number is
>   combined with the suffix 月 (-gatsu, "month").

This is why `culc.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames` returns:

`string[13] { "1月", "2月", "3月", "4月", "5月", "6月", "7月", "8月", "9月", "10月", "11月", "12月", "" }`

Then abbreviated version is without "月" suffix.

Other references:

- [CultureInfo for Japanese language not setting up DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames property correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26650666/cultureinfo-for-japanese-language-not-setting-up-datetimeformat-abbreviatedmonth)
- [Japanese abbreviated month formatting with the counter kanji](https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize/issues/92)